# Attempt at a Word Wrap Program in C++

Tags: c++, word-wrap

Okay, so I'm trying to make a word wrap program to implement in my future programs and game attempts, to make it easier on myself to write the story parts. I'm not entirely sure what's wrong, I'm doing what I figured would be the best way to do this, but it appears to have some issues that I have no idea how to explain. Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Here's the code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

void wordWrapPrinting(string a);

int main()
{
     cout << "Hello, my name is ________. This is a test of my word wrap program. If it works as      intended, it will correctly fix strings such as this one and make sure that none of the words are cut off and carried over to another line. This will make writing stories for games much easiser for both myself and Kevin, and maybe even the whole class. This was a request from _____ (sort of, he was complaining about it and I said I could probably make one). Hopefully this works.";
     cout << endl;
     cout << endl;
     cout << endl;
     cout << endl;
     cout << endl;
     wordWrapPrinting("Hello, my name is ________. This is a test of my word wrap program. If it works as intended, it will correctly fix strings such as this one and make sure that none of the words are cut off and carried over to another line. This will make writing stories for games much easiser for both myself and Kevin, and maybe even the whole class. This was a request from _____ (sort of, he was complaining about it and I said I could probably make one). Hopefully this works.");
}

void wordWrapPrinting(string a)
{
    int iCounter = 0;
    bool spaced = false;
    for(int i=0; i < a.size(); i++)
    {
        /*if(i == 81)
            spaced = false;
        else if(i == 161)
            spaced = false;
        else if(i == 241)
            spaced = false;
        else if(i == 321)
            spaced = false;
        else if(i == 401)
            spaced = false;*/

        if(a[i] != ' ')
        {
            if(i == 80 && a[i] != ' ' /*&& spaced == false*/)
            {
                while(a[i] != ' ')
                {
                    iCounter++;
                    i--;
                }
                if(a[i] == ' ')
                {
                    a[i] = '\n';
                    i += iCounter;
                    //spaced = true;
                }
            }
            else if(i == 160 && a[i] != ' ' /*&& spaced == false*/)
            {
                while(a[i] != ' ')
                {
                    iCounter++;
                    i--;
                }
                if(a[i] == ' ')
                {
                    a[i] = '\n';
                    i += iCounter;
                    //spaced = true;
                }

            }
            else if(i == 240 && a[i] != ' ' /*&& spaced == false*/)
            {
                while(a[i] != ' ')
                {
                    iCounter++;
                    i--;
                }
                if(a[i] == ' ')
                {
                    a[i] = '\n';
                    i += iCounter;
                    //spaced = true;
                }
            }
            else if(i == 320 && a[i] != ' ' /*&& spaced == false*/)
            {
                while(a[i] != ' ')
                {
                    iCounter++;
                    i--;
                }
                if(a[i] == ' ')
                {
                    a[i] = '\n';
                    i += iCounter;
                    //spaced = true;
                }
            }
            else if(i == 400 && a[i] != ' ' /*&& spaced == false*/)
            {
                while(a[i] != ' ')
                {
                    iCounter++;
                    i--;
                }
                if(a[i] == ' ')
                {
                    a[i] = '\n';
                    i += iCounter;
                    //spaced = true;
                }
            }
            else if(i == 480 && a[i] != ' ' /*&& spaced == false*/)
            {
                while(a[i] != ' ')
                {
                    iCounter++;
                    i--;
                }
                if(a[i] == ' ')
                {
                    a[i] = '\n';
                    i += iCounter;
                    //spaced = true;
                }
            }
            else if(i == 560 && a[i] != ' ' /*&& spaced == false*/)
            {
                while(a[i] != ' ')
                {
                    iCounter++;
                    i--;
                }
                if(a[i] == ' ')
                {
                    a[i] = '\n';
                    i += iCounter;
                    //spaced = true;
                }
            }
        }
        else
            if(a[i] != ' ')
                if(i == 80 || i == 160 || i == 240 || i == 320 || i == 400 || i == 480 || i ==  560)
                    a[i] = '\n';
        /*if(((i >= 75 && i <=80) || (i >= 155 && i <=160) || (i >= 235 && i <=240) || (i >= 315 && i <= 320) || (i >= 375 && i <= 400) || (i >= 475 && i <= 480)) && a[i] != ' ' && spaced != false) 
        {
            while(a[i] != ' ')
                iCounter++;
            if(a[i] == ' ')
            {
                a[i] = '\n';
                spaced = true;
            }
        }
        else
            if(((i >= 75 && i <=80) || (i >= 155 && i <=160) || (i >= 235 && i <=240) || (i >= 315 && i <= 320) || (i >= 375 && i <= 400) || (i >= 475 && i <= 480)) && a[i] == ' ' && spaced != false)
            {
                a[i] = '\n';
                spaced = true;
            }*/
    }
    cout << a << endl;
}
```

Comment: Forgot to mention, the commented out stuff were parts of my previous attempts.

Comment: You may want to look at the `%` operator. If I have over 560 characters, your program stops line wrapping...

Comment: It is hard to know what is the expected output and the problems you are having.

Comment: @mstuff63 As to your program to do word wrap -- it would be easier if you just broke up the line you read in into individual words (tokenize the line, maybe placing each word in an entry in a `vector`).  Then starting with an empty line, place each word on the line until you get an overflow on the line.  Then you wrap to the next line and continue.  Yes, some details are missing such as treating multiple spaces between each word, but it would be much  simpler to implement (IMO).

Comment: Well, first of all, your code is long and complicated.  http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/875d314b3854d3f6

Comment: @Quirliom I know, this is mostly just for the games that my friend and I are making in our C++ class, the longest line he had was 445 characters, so I just made it a little longer. I fixed it anyway though, for future circumstances.

Comment: @mstuff63 Using % would make your code *a lot* easier to read and understand, rather than just repeating the same code 7 times.

Answer (score 1):

As others have stated, break up the sentence into words.

If the current position on the line + sizeof(word) is greater than the right margin, process the line and place the new word at the left margin of the next (new line).

If you are really good at this, you could split words and use hyphens.

Or if you have more time, you could justify the text.

By the way, if you are on a windowing system, you will have to convert the word length into pixel length.  Words in different fonts have different widths.  Very few fonts are fixed-space.

Comment: while I'm sure that method would work, can you or any one else tell me what's wrong with my original code, because I can't figure it out, and if I'm not shown what is wrong or find out what is wrong, I could run into a problem like this again in the future. Also, I don't want to have to write a whole new program if no one can tell me what is making my current one not work.

Comment: @mstuff63 - `because I can't figure it out, and if I'm not shown what is wrong or find out what is wrong, I could run into a problem like this again in the future`  *You* wrote the code, therefore you had a design already planned before you wrote anything, correct?  So did you use your debugger to debug your code so that *you* can determine where the program deviates from your design?